# Laravel 5.4: TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm sorry guys to post again this issue that seems impacting everyone who use Laravel.

I did / changed everything I had to change to avoid this error, but sometimes not always I got

> "TokenMismatchException"

Does anyone know why or have an explication please? Cause I feel like I lose a lot of time trying to fix this sh***** issue....

thanks a lot

Comment: The exact approach you need to take depends on whether you're using a `<form>`, AJAX, or if these are something like a server-to-server API request. The duplicate thread has various answers that deal with each of these. Fundamentally, you've got a `POST` route you're either a) not sending a CSRF token to or b) sending the *wrong* token to. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: (Side note: Think very carefully before you do one of the "just disable it" answers. CSRF protection is a **good thing**. Understand what it is, and what it protects you from, before you go turning it off.)

Comment: thanks, I don't want to turn it off, but since I began I might spent 2 complete days trying to make it work again cause I didn't change anything yesterday and I was properly working :/ anayway thank you for your time

Comment: If it was previously working, and you haven't changed anything, I'd check that your Laravel app is saving sessions properly. The user's token is stored in one.